# Highest Performing Base station based on data

Tags: excel, telecommunication

I've been given an exercise based on Excel and I'm a bit puzzled on how to approach the question.

The question states to show "Highest performing Base Station in terms of revenue by Area, Region, Product and total revenue."

I know that I'll have to use a PivotChart to illustrate the data but how would I go about listing it?

My x-axis would obviously be the base station but I'm unsure whether or not my solution is correct or not.

This screen shot is a sample of the data below:

[image]

I don't know how to present this in a graph, or more precisely what type of graph would be best suited for this question or for that matter, maybe multiple graphs?

This is my current solution which I think is wrong because I have a feeling I'm missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question carefully, the question you have to answer, stated more simply, is "list base stations by descending product and total revenue for each area and region."  So there's your first answer: always simplify the problem statement as much as possible, and have the person asking to accept your reformulation of the question.  This will simplify the process of answering.

Next, what does each row of your data represent?  Is each row a single time period?  If base stations are to be stack-ranked, then the time interval should be explicit to assure that the comparisons are relevant and "apples-to-apples".  The pivot table will like this, too.

If this reformulated question is accurate, then it seems to me many graphs will be required, 1 each to show area voice, SMS, data, and total revenue for each area and region.

But rather than create a zillion individual graphs, insert an abstraction layer between the pivot table and the graph.  By this, I mean create an intermediate data table.  A single graph will show the values in the data table, meaning the graph's SERIES() function will use this intermediate data table.

The data table itself will be driven by the Pivot table and by user input. Potential user inputs will be the product, area, and region.  You'll need a bit of logic to prevent the user from over-specifying.

If the way I've written this is unclear, try this.  Create a pivot table based on the data shown. Set up the pivot so that every displayable value is a value in the pivot. Don't worry that the pivot table will be ugly, it will never be seen by end users. Next, enter an equals sign ("=") in any blank cell, then click anywhere in the values areas of the Pivot table.  The formula you just created will look like this.

=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Total Revenue", 'Worksheet'!$A$1, "Area", "Nadi", "Region", "Western", "Product", "Voice")

I've added spaces after each comma in the formula so that it will line break naturally.  There will be no such spaces in the actual formula.

Then, substitute a reference to user input for the values in each of "Area", "Region", and "Product.

For example, if your user input for "Area" is in cell $X$1, the formula changes to this:

=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Total Revenue", 'Worksheet'!$A$1, "Area", $X$1, "Region", "Western", "Product", "Voice")

Repeat for the other user inputs.  You will need more abstraction to allow the user to select some of the inputs with the remaining inputs being generated formulaically, what I called "over-specifying", above.  "This is left as an exercise for the reader."  Every value in your intermediate data table will be displayed by a variation of this GETPIVOTDATA() function.

In my opinion, the coolest thing about this approach is that as new revenue data is added to the source, you only need to refresh the pivot table to include the new data.  So if the same question is asked again next month, quarter or year, answering it will be trivial.

I've written a series of articles, 6 articles so far, specifically for Technical Telecoms workers using Excel to address BTS-related reporting issues.  Here's a link to the first article:   https://bangkokbeachtelecom.com/excel-project-tracker-with-the-coolest-excel-function-ever/

Good luck.

Comment: Russel, each row is a customer represented by their mobile phone number.

Comment: Really?  An individual customer spent $1,958 at site ATS Nadi?  Perhaps these dollar amounts represent Taiwanese dollars.  But regardless, in that case, it seems unnecessary to include the phone number in the source data.

Comment: I've added an updated screen shot showing the Customer column

Comment: @rahul if you wouldn't mind to send me some of the data, say 200 rows, I'll have a go creating the workbook I described in my answer.  The approach is general enough to be genuinely useful in many situations; your example is specific enough to allow many people to relate to the technique. Consider connecting with me on LinkedIn, the data could be passed to me there. 
 https://www.linkedin.com/in/russelllundberg

Comment: I wrote up all the activities I took with the OP and posted to my blog, https://bangkokbeachtelecom.com/excel-telecom-managers/ 

Follow me on LinkedIn, see the link in the previous comment, if you want to be updated about more articles like this.